# Google Cloud IoT Core and Pubsub Pricing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I am using google IoT core and pubsub services for my IoT devices. I am publishing data using pubsub to the database. but I think its quite expensive to store every data into the database. I have some data like if the device is on or off and a configuration file which has some parameter which I need to process my IoT payload. Now I am not able to understand if configuration and state topic in IoT is expensive or not? and how long the data is stored in the config topic and is it feasible that whenever the parameter is changed in the config file it publish that data into config topic? and what if I publish my state of a device that if it is online or not every 3 seconds or more into the state topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing different things. There is Cloud IoT, where you have a device registry, with metadata, configuration and states. You also have PubSub topic in which you can publish message about IoT payload that can contain configuration data (I assume that is that you means in this sentence: "it publish that data into config topic").

In definitive it's simple.

- All the management operations on Cloud IoT are free (device registration, configuration, metadata,...). There is no limitation and no duration limit. The only one which exists in the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas) for rate limit and configuration size.
- The inbound and outbound traffic from and to the IoT devices is billed as [described here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/pricing)
- If you use PubSub for pushing your messages, Cloud Functions (or Cloud Run, or other compute option), a database (Cloud SQL or Datastore/Firestore), all these services are billed as usual, there is no relation with Cloud IoT service & billing. The constraints of each services are applied as a regular usage. For example, a PubSub message live up to 7 days (by default) in a subscription and until it hasn't acknowledged.

**EDIT**

*Ok, got it, I took time to understood what you wanted to achieve.*

The state is designed for getting the internal representation of the devices, but the current limitation doesn't allow you to update it automatically when you received message.

You have 2 solutions:

- Either you can update your devices and send an update message only when its state changes (it's for this kind of use case that the feature is designed!)
- Or, let the device published the messages every 3 seconds, but in the event PubSub topic. Get the events in a function which get the [state list](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices.states/list), get the first one (the most recent) and compare the value with the PubSub message. If different, [update the state](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiotdevice/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/setState). This workflow also work with external database like Datastore or Firestore.

Comment: Yes, ia m talking about Cloud IoT configuration and states. As when we set the configuration it publishes it to a pubsub topic of '/devices/DEVICE_ID/config ' and device publish its state to '/devices/DEVICE_ID/state'.. now my question is when i set the config will it stored there forever until i update it or delete it? and does it cost anything as it is stored in IoT core?...and the second is about the state that if i publish my state every 3 second to '/devices/DEVICE_ID/state' topic.. then it would be the normal pubsub cost that we usually pay to publish data on a pubsub topic?

Comment: and it states :State updates per project is 6,000 per min*" in the link you have provided, so that means if i have 1000 devices and i am updating states every 3 seconds and as it is far more that 6000 per min i would not be able to use the state topic to publish data over it?

Comment: Is the state really change every 3 seconds? Or do you receive a message every 3 seconds with, mostly the same state as before?

Comment: About your first comment, you pay the bandwidth on Cloud IoT and the PubSub messages (and, for example, the Cloud Function which will consume the PubSub message). You don't pay for the state and config storage on Cloud IOT, and for the device registration/management. Device data (state, config, metadata) are kept without limit.

Comment: Its the same message coming after 3 seconds i.e. {"ts":"15814060872,"status": "online"}

Comment: and if the same message can be sent without limit we can also exclude timstamp and just leave it with {"status": "online"}

Comment: Right now we are not updating the device state thats why i wanted to use the state as status for the devices

Comment: I edited my answer, Hope that solve your current use case